# Negative ping time?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ping, latency

This is the first time I've seen this and I'm not sure what it means;

```
64 bytes from 74.125.93.99: icmp_seq=6233 ttl=53 time=545.493 ms  
64 bytes from 74.125.93.99: icmp_seq=6234 ttl=53 time=776.093 ms  
64 bytes from 74.125.93.99: icmp_seq=6235 ttl=53 time=-705.731 ms  
64 bytes from 74.125.93.99: icmp_seq=6236 ttl=53 time=52.549 ms   
64 bytes from 74.125.93.99: icmp_seq=6237 ttl=53 time=44.470 ms
```

Has anyone ever seen a negative ping time before? A friend of mine told me he saw it once on a wireless link, and this was over a wireless connection, but.. how does that happen?

Comment: Do you have an AMD processor?

Comment: Just a temporary rift in the space-time continuum.  Nothing to worry about.  Now where did I put the keys to my DeLorean?

Comment: I don't remember specifically which machine I ran the test on, but the only 3 that I could have run it on are all Intel (one Intel desktop, one Macbook Pro, one Mac Mini).

Comment: Negative ping lag is a glitch in the matrix. It happens when they change something.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Did NTP or Windows Time Service sync the system clock during the ping?

Comment: Excellent question, that could be it.  Unfortunately I don't remember exactly what time I did the ping so I can't check the logs for an NTP sync that lines up.

Comment: That would be freaking odd, but +1 for great troubleshooting point.

Comment: With no better answer provided, and not being able to come up with a more plausible solution from the time this happened until now, I'm accepting this answer because I think it's the most likely explanation for how this happened.  Thanks.

Comment: I just encountered the same problem on a virtual machine, and can confirm that NTP correcting the time drift was the issue. `service ntpd stop` on CentOS fixed that (but will create other problems, obviously). See [this very interesting question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/117422/how-can-i-resolve-the-drifting-clock-for-my-virtual-machine) for more info.

Answer (score 4):

I find it hard to believe, but [this discussion](http://forums.pcper.com/showthread.php?t=430695) seems to indicate this is behavior from certain AMD CPUs.

Personally, I wouldn't worry about it and assume it's a conceptual flaw in ICMP... Maybe a packet that went through a different path or something weird involving machines/routers with their clocks set differently.

Comment: From the linked discussion, I wouldn't lean towards conceptual flaw in ICMP. It appears that AMD has clock skew between the two cores which causes the negative interpretation of the time.

Comment: @evan: But 0.7 seconds is a *huge* discrepancy!

Comment: the report you get from ping doesn't have anything to do with clocks on external routers, it is the difference in time from when the packet is sent to it's destination and the reply is received back to the host. It is clocked by the host.

Comment: @Mechanical snail You're right, that's extremely large, but the discussion linked says the skew grows over time. If the processor has been running for an extended period of time .7 seconds is not too absurd. It would be interesting to see if the problem only arises after the processor has been running for a while.

Comment: @Evan: I mean that 0.7 seconds is bound to cause more serious bugs than this, so we probably would have already heard of it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's a bug in the way the `ping` command times the packets and is aggravated by AMD processors more than Intel.

The functions that are used for high resolution timing in windows are `QueryPerformanceCounter` and `QueryPerformanceFrequency`.

Unfortunately, they are broken for multi-core processors as these processors do not return the same numbers.

The fix to ping is to set thread affinity in `ping`.  I doubt it's doing this which would explain the negative timing.  There are also patches from AMD and MS which are supposed to help sort it out.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is not limited to AMD processors, but it seems to affect XP quite a bit. To date, and after a few years of searching for answers, I know a quick fix, but I can't do it to servers that won't reappear by remote after booting.

To reset TCP/IP (and timings), open an admin CMD window and enter the following:

```
ipconfig /flushdns
arp -d
gpupdate /force
netsh int ip reset null
netsh winsock reset
```

Now, you MUST reboot. Network adapter reverts to DHCP, so beware remoters.

So what happens here?

For some reason, TCP/IP has a time stamp it uses to calculate timing, and it gets fudged somehow. I used to see it all the time at one location, but it's finally stopped. Unfortunately, it continues at the warehouse I manage. Tonight, all points seem to be stuck at 237ms, but 2 popped back with multiple pings.

`pingpath` is a very handy utility, and I will be using this more often. Unfortunately, it came up with the same results...

Sad thing, this clears ping miscounts in games also.

note- if you want to see the log file, replace null with a filename, such as `c:\log.txt`
-- Null just means no file (technically)