# Negative ping on OSX?

Tags: macos, networking, ping

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Negative ping time?](https://superuser.com/questions/310271/negative-ping-time)

Running the ping command for a very long time, I get this result:

```
384063 packets transmitted, 380228 packets received, 1.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = -372.658/11.228/6468.363/55.076 ms
```

How can the minimum time be -372.658ms? It seems to defy logic that a packet would arrive BEFORE I ask for it...

I'm running OSX 10.7.4

Comment: Did you take a look [here](http://superuser.com/questions/310271/negative-ping-time) in case you have a process syncing the clock on your system ? Do you have an Intel CPU on this Mac ?

Comment: My money's on NTP.

Comment: Your connection must be fast.

Comment: There can only be one explanation: your packets are travelling backwards through time. You should probably check your cables for any wormholes...